# Java recursion how to calculate sum of each digit

Tags: java, recursion

I can't seem to solve this one. Recursion is not my strongest point.

If asked to write a console application where the program calculates the product of each digit of an entered number.

for example:

```
input = 1234 -> output = 24
input = 1230 -> output = 0
```

this needs to be in recursion.

Can you help me please ? thanks in advance

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and what is not working like you'd expect.  You will not receive a good response here if you do not have any code to show.

Comment: You first of all need a way to extract a digit and then to remove a digit. So for example getting the `1` from `1230` and then modifying it to `230`. Then `2` and `30`, then `3` and `0`. You can do so by using `/ 10` and `% 10`.

Answer (score 1):

For recursive solutions, you need to define two things
1. Base case
2. Recursive case

For your example, 
1. Base case - For a String with single number input, method should return itself.
2. Recursive case - If the input is a String with many numbers, you need to get the multiplication.

```
void test() {
    String x = "1234";
    System.out.println(recurs(x));
}

int recurs(String x) {
     if (x.length() == 1) {
         return Integer.parseInt(x);
     } else {
         return recurs(x.substring(0,1)) * recurs(x.substring(1));
     }
}
```

Comment: Multiplication? OP is trying to sum up the digits, not to multiplicate them. Other than that, good answer.

Comment: Yeah, his title and example code are two different things. That is why the confusion. My example tally with his code not the title

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
public static int prod (int v) {
    return v == 0 ? 1 : v%10 * prod(v/10);
}
```

If you want to define an `instance` or `static` `lambda` you can do it as follows:

```
IntFunction<Integer> prod1 = n->n == 0 ? 1 : n%10 * this.prod1.apply(n/10);

static IntFunction<Integer> prod2 n->n == 0 ? 1 n%10 * ClassName.prod2.apply(n/10);

System.out.println(prod.apply(1234)); // prints 24.
```

In each of these cases it recursively calls the method
resulting in the following being placed on the call stack:

```
1234
123
12
1
```

Then it uses the remainder operator (`%`) on each of those as it returns to get the product of the last digits resulting in 1 * 2 * 3 * 4.

And finally, since the products can get large, you may want to use a `BigInteger` version.

```
public static BigInteger bigProd(BigInteger b) {
    return b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) ? 
            BigInteger.ONE :
                b.mod(BigInteger.TEN).multiply(bigProd(b.divide(BigInteger.TEN)));
}

    System.out.println(bigProd(new 
         BigInteger("9282223929192298837394749389484938494")));
```

which prints

> 5706072528759010784968704

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(" PLease enter Number:"); 
    int number = in. nextInt();
    int recursion =1;
    while (number%10 >= 0 && number >0){

        recursion = recursion* (number%10); // get the last number and multiple 
        number = number/10;
    }
    System.out.println("Recursion"+recursion);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int product(int number) {
    if (number / 10 > 0) {
        return product(number / 10) * (number % 10);
    } else {
        return number % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's best to include some commentary on why the code in your answer is the correct solution.